# Error in compiling a file to static binary using Clang

Tags: c, clang

I am using ubuntu 20 and i am trying to compile my C code which uses md5 function from "<openssl/md5.h>"  into a static binary.

The problem is that I get an error:  `undefined reference to MD5`.
if i compile it without static it works ok.
I have tried the following methods and same error:

```
clang --static -I/usr/include/openssl -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcrypto -lssl binary.c -o binary_out

 clang --static -I/usr/include/openssl -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcrypto binary.c -o binary_out

 clang --static -I/usr/include/openssl -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcrypto binary.c -o binary_out
```

Comment: The order of the libraries you link in matters. Try moving `binary.c` to the beginning of the your build line (or at least in front of the `-l`'s). This is for gcc, but probably worth looking at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc